# How to detect end of _find in CouchDB?

Tags: bash, couchdb

Using CouchDB (3.1.1 on windows) I want to iterate on the results of a `/db/_find` using the bookmark mechanism.
It works pretty well, but I don't know how to end the looping. The code is similar to this:

```
while true
do
    curl -s -X POST $dburl/db/_find -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"selector":{bla bla},"bookmark":'$b'}' > result.dat

    Extract bookmark from result.dat and assign it to b variable
done
```

How to end such loop? The result contains a valid bookmark even when there are no more documents to be returned and curl always succeeds.

Thanks for your help!
mario

Comment: Compare the number of results returned against the `limit`.  If number of results < limit, you are done. See [Pagination](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html?highlight=_find#pagination)

Comment: Yes, this works, but it is a little complex to do in a bash script. I'm not very fluent in `jq` but this could be a way to investigate. If only the last bookmark returned had a special value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion RamblinRose!
Here is the solution that works beautifully:

```
n=200
b=null

while [ $n = 200 ]
do
    x=`curl -s -X POST $db/kb/_find -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"selector": {bla bla},"limit":200,"bookmark":'$b'}' | tee -a $tmp | jq '.bookmark,(.docs | length)'`

    a=($x)

    b=${a[0]}
    n=${a[1]}
done
```

Comment: This is a rare case where one should accept one's answer 